# Fusion two dataframe by the same row name

Tags: python, pandas

For example, two dataframes named **df1**, **df2** showd like this:

```
### df1
Name    Code   Mass
5N11     s1     0.1545
5N12     NaN     0.22 
5N13     s3   0.2123
5N15     s5    0.1486
5N17     NaN    0.2100

### df2
Name    Code   Mass
5N12     s2    0.22 
5N13     NaN   0.2123
5N14     s4    0.35
5N16     s6    0.07
5N17     s7    0.2100
```

Some background introduction:

- **df1** and **df2** are two dataframes both contain part of data of some items.
- Some **Name** in **df1** and **df2** are same.
- The **Mass** corrsponding the same **Name** in **df1** and **df2** are equal.
- Some rows containt the finite **Code**, some are not.

What I'm trying to do is to merge this two dataframe together by the **Name** and combine with its **code** and **mass**.

#### Update

My attempt seems work!

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index= True)
df = df.dropna(subset= ["Code"])
df = pd.merge(df.groupby('Name').sum().reset_index(),
              df[['Name', 'Code',"Mass"]].drop_duplicates(),
              how='right')
```

It seems like reproducing the right result.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Start with `df1` and fill in from `df2` where `df1` is missing.  This **requires** that we set the index for each as the 'Name'

### Quick Solution

```
df1.set_index('Name').combine_first(df2.set_index('Name'))
```

### Full Solution

#### Setup

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text1 = """Name    Code   Mass
5N11     s1     0.1545
5N12     NaN     0.22 
5N13     s3   0.2123
5N15     s5    0.1486
5N17     NaN    0.2100"""

text2 = """Name    Code   Mass
5N12     s2    0.22 
5N13     NaN   0.2123
5N14     s4    0.35
5N16     s6    0.07
5N17     s7    0.2100"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text1), delim_whitespace=True)

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text2), delim_whitespace=True)
```

#### combine results

```
df1.set_index('Name').combine_first(df2.set_index('Name')).reset_index()
```

Looks like:

```
   Name Code    Mass
0  5N11   s1  0.1545
1  5N12   s2  0.2200
2  5N13   s3  0.2123
3  5N14   s4  0.3500
4  5N15   s5  0.1486
5  5N16   s6  0.0700
6  5N17   s7  0.2100
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it seems that the result was wrong. Some rows didn't have the finite `Code`

Comment: This solution gets the results you asked for.  If you ran this for a larger data set and found missing `Code` values then that implies that `Code` is missing from both `df1` and `df2` for that `Name`.

Comment: that was a lot easier than I thought it would be. Super helpful!